# What's the fastest way to read images from urls?

Tags: python, image, url, keras

I want to make a generator that generates batches of images from urls to train a `keras` model. I have another generator that feeds me images urls.

What I currently do is download the image to disk and then load the image from the disk.

```
def loadImage(URL):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(URL) as url:
        with open('temp.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(url.read())

    img_path = 'temp.jpg'
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(125, 125))
    os.remove(img_path)
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    return x

def imageGenerator(batch_size):
    i = 0
    batch = []
    for URL in imageUrlGenerator():
        if i>batch_size:
            yield batch
            batch = []
            i=0
        batch.append(loadImage(URL))
        i+=1
```

This works but I wonder if there isn't a faster way to load images from the web without having to write and read in/from disk.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are actually using `keras` and that this [`image.load_img`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/69e47e49920256903e34cf8aaf37fff8d64a3ddc/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py#L78) is the method you are calling, it would [call a function](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/69e47e49920256903e34cf8aaf37fff8d64a3ddc/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py#L109) which should ultimately be [`PIL.Image.open`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open).  In the documentation for `PIL.image.open`, the first argument `fp` could be a string filename (which is what you are currently passing), or a stream-like object that implements `read`, `seek`, and `tell`.  While the object returned by `urllib.request.urlopen` does provide all three methods, it does not implement `seek` at all, so it cannot be used directly.  However, the entire buffer can be read into an `BytesIO` object which does implement `seek`, so it should be usable.  Putting this together, your `loadImage` function may be reduced to something like the following:

```
from io import BytesIO

def loadImage(URL):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(URL) as url:
        img = image.load_img(BytesIO(url.read()), target_size=(125, 125))

    return image.img_to_array(img)
```

This keeps the images downloaded fully in memory.

Comment: Sounds good, however using the keras function ```image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(125, 125)) ``` I can choose a target size, how do you recommend doing that with this method? (having in mind that speed is important)

Comment: @CristianDesivo it should work as expected.  I now updated my example to be more reflective of what you are trying to do, since I had missed out a few bits when I copied your code.

Comment: missing imports: `from urllib.request import urlopen` and `from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array`

Comment: And more importantly: it doesn't work anymore with an URL string: `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO`: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/issues/293

Comment: @kilgoretrout Yes, you are correct, [this was the commit](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/pull/261/commits/fa8af4702062cee4e5c9563d279b11bbf12b5913) that modified the direct invocation of `pil_image.open`, to the `open` read into `BytesIO` that caused this breakage.  A quick fix would be for that relevant code section to check whether or not the provided argument was already a `BytesIO` instance, and use that directly if it's the case.

Answer (score 6):

This is the simplest solution I've seen.

```
from PIL import Image
from urllib import request
from io import BytesIO

url = "https://github.com/ironmanciti/MachineLearningBasic/blob/master/datasets/TransferLearningData/watch.jpg?raw=true"
res = request.urlopen(url).read()
Sample_Image = Image.open(BytesIO(res)).resize((150,150))

plt.imshow(Sample_Image)
```

Comment: because of the issue I commented above, this should now be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Got this from [Github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11684#issuecomment-601142362) issues

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import requests

def loadImage(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    img_bytes = BytesIO(response.content)
    img = Image.open(img_bytes)
    img = img.convert('RGB')
    img = img.resize((250,250), Image.NEAREST)
    img = img_to_array(img)
    return img
```

Answer (score 0):

2 Quick fixes:

- Consider moving the `os.remove(img_path)` line. I assume this is removing the file from your drive, but I'm thinking you can save this for the end. Your model just needs all the information possible. Once it has the information, you can either asynchronously begin deleting the files, or just wait until the model is trained and cleanup. Doing it one by one as you have, may be slowing you down.
- Use fast storage devices and configurations, SSD, USB 3.x, USB C, etc.

Other fixes:

- Is it possible to hold things in a cache?
- Could you hold things in an array? I don't think so, but it may be possible.
- Do you need the whole image? Could you decrease the quality of the image?
- How nested is the image? Parsing for the image likely isn't an issue, but it can't hurt to check.